# How to add db2 support for php5

Tags: php, db2

I already have db2 installed in my Ubuntu. And I installed PHP5 too. Now I want to provide db2 support to PHP5. How can I do that? My db2 installation path is `/opt/ibm/db2/V9.7`

Comment: find/install a db2 module for php...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ibm-db2.installation.php